# Bootstrap 3 Carousel only semi-responsive. Weird

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am having issues with my carousel using bootstrap3.  The image itself is responsive, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make the caption, and button also responsive.  Haven't had much luck finding a clear answer. See

http://windstarwd.com/testman/

View the above page, then make your browser narrow and you will see the issues

for the "page header" (above the nav bar) i was able to get the phone number (h2) responsive by adding:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .my-header > div > h2 {
  font-size: smaller;
  }
}
```

But I am having trouble with the social media icons stacking and throwing off the site, and the carousel caption and buttons getting shoved off the top when in mobile.  It would be ideal to have the 32x32 social icons show normally, but the 16x16 when < 768px

So I guess I'm having two issues here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same media query for the top buttons, like

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .socialIcons > img {
     width: 16px;
     height: 16px;
  }
}
```

or use a second second icon bar that will be shown if the screen size is too small, hiding the big icons bar, with the bootstrap attribute   `.visible-sm` and `.hidden-sm` ([bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)).

For the carousel caption, you can once again use the media queries to set a different width when screen size < 768px, or define a width with percents instead of fixed size.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Wors good enough for me thanks!  Messing with the carousel buttons/caption to get that responsive as well